# Dictionary and Input: if the `input` contains any of the keys I want to print the value

Tags: python, dictionary, input, chatbot

I'm trying to build kind of a  simple chatbot, but when the `input` is something out of the dictionary the `else` block is working as it should be...

I want to print the `value` even if the `input` is something from the `keys` and some other words.
for example:

text something: hi there    answer: hello

so, if the `input` contains any of the keys i want to print the value.

please let me know if you know a way to make this. Thank you.

```
words = {"good night": ["nighty night", "good night", "sleep well"],
         "good morning": ["good morning", "wakey-wakey!", "rise and shine!"],
         "hi": ["hello", "hey", "hola"]
         }


text_punk = input("text something: ")

if text_punk in words:
    punk = random.choice(words[text_punk])

    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
else:
    print("problem!")
```

Comment: in this case you need to check if the that are the key in dictionary are present in the input text that the, like `if any( k in text_punk for k in word):...`

Comment: thank you @Copperfield for your answer. I tried that however I am getting a KeyError when I run the code.

Comment: oh right, you need to also determine which of the key give the match, the code above only said is there is a match

Comment: yes and  do you have any idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following.

```
import random
words = {"good night": ["nighty night", "good night", "sleep well"],
         "good morning": ["good morning", "wakey-wakey!", "rise and shine!"],
         "hi": ["hello", "hey", "hola"]
         }

text_punk = input("text something: ")

greet_words = words.keys() #check if your key words is in input_text.
word_available = [word for word in greet_words if word in text_punk]

if word_available: # if words are available take the first of key.
    punk = random.choice(words[word_available[0]])

    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
else:
    print("problem!")
```

Comment: thanks a lot @shivankgtm for your help, I am really appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

checking if a given text is a dictionary only give a result if the exact text is in the dictionary, so if you check `"hi" in words` it work because `"hi"` is one of the key of the dict, this doesn't work for partials check of `"hi there"`, for that you need to check if any of the key in the dict are present in the input text, so something like

```
text_punk = input("text something: ")
for msj,replies in words.items():#with items we get both the key and its value in one go
    if msj in text_punk:
        punk = random.choice(replies)
        print(punk)
        break #with this we stop the loop at the first match
```

Comment: thank you @Copperfield for your time and help.. I am really thankful, this one also worked well. Thanks a lot :)